# jdbc add hours, minutes and seconds in ORACLE when date is 01/01/1900

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have two databases in Oracle (12c) and a JAVA (ojdbc 7) process that moves information between both of them. This process is currently working perfectly with a lot of different types of columns and tables, but for some reasons when it should move a column DATE with the value "01/01/1900", this process add hours, minutes and seconds (always the same) to convert the date in 01/01/1900 01:14:44.

The process works OK with any other value. Even it works in other environments (development and pre-production) with aparently the sames conditions and versions, although clearly something should be different...

Does someone know when it could be the problem?

Part of the code:

```
//reader method
    public static Map<String, Object> getRegistroFromBDON(Connection connBDON, String tabla, List<String> pkCols, Map<String, Object> pkValues, Timestamp fecUltEjecucion, List<String> columnNames) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> registro = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        List<Object> queryValues = new ArrayList<Object>();
        int regIndex = 0;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        InputStream inStream = null;

        try {
            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("select * from ");
            query.append(tabla).append(" where fec_ini_vigencia < ? ");
            queryValues.add(fecUltEjecucion);

            for(int i = 0; i < pkCols.size(); i++) {
                query.append("and ").append(pkCols.get(i)).append(" = ? ");
                queryValues.add(pkValues.get("Value" + (i + 1)));
            }

            ps = connBDON.prepareStatement(query.toString());
            int index = 1;
            for(Object obj : queryValues)
                ps.setObject(index++, obj);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()) {
                registro = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                for(String col : columnNames) 
                    registro.put(col, rs.getObject(col));
            }   
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if(inStream != null)
                inStream.close();
            if(fos != null)
                fos.close();
            if(ps != null)
                ps.close();
            if(rs != null)
                rs.close();
        }
        return registro;
    }

//writer method
    public static void insertaRegistroBI(Connection conn, String tableName, List<String> columnas, List<String> columnasBI, Map<String, Object> registro, String concepto, Timestamp fecActual) throws SQLException, Exception {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        List<Object> queryValues = new ArrayList<Object>();
        File blob = null;
        FileInputStream in = null;

        try {
            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("insert into ");
            query.append(tableName).append(" (");

            StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder(") values (?, ?");

            for(String columna : columnas) {
                query.append(", ").append(columna);
                values.append(", ?");
                queryValues.add(registro.get(columna));
            }

            values.append(") ");

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(query.toString() + values.toString());
            int index = 1;
            for(Object obj : queryValues) {
                ps.setObject(index++, obj);
            }

            ps.executeUpdate(); 
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if(in != null)
                in.close();
            if(blob != null)
                blob.delete();
            if(ps != null)
                ps.close();
            if(rs != null)
                rs.close();
        }
    }
```

Thanks!
Regards

Comment: Show us the code. **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: The source date value is not '01/01/1990'; it has a time component, even if that is midnight. Have you just left that off for brevity, or is it possible the source also has the same time, and you're just displaying the dates with different formats in the two DBs? If it is changing it from midnight to 01:14:44 then we'd need to see the code; also check there are no triggers modifying the value as it's inserted in the new DB. (Seems unlikely, but still...)

Comment: The source data value is "01/01/1900 00:00:00" and there isn't any trigger in the db. I'm goint to include a part of the code in the question.

Comment: I've added part of the code, but how you can see there isn't a special transformation of the information, so it has no sense...

Comment: I suggest you download 12.2 ojdbc8.jar and try that. Let us know the results.

Comment: I use the same version of ojdbc in other environments where it works correctly so I think this is not the problem, but I will try. I think the problem could be relationated with the bd configuration but I can't find differences between environments... I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be related to java timezone.

If you have set the timezone something like -Duser.timezone=Europe/Madrid, then try with GMT+ format...